# Why does Windows guest provisioning fail when removing a WinRM log?

Tags: windows, powershell, vagrant, winrm

I'm not sure where to start with this problem. I'm using the [`modernIE\w7-ie8`](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/modernIE/boxes/w7-ie8) box. The first time I start it (`vagrant up` from scratch), it needs to be manually tweaked to get Vagrant to connect:

- Continue/cancel through a startup recovery/repair dialog
- Change the network type from Public to Work/Home

After that, I have three short shell provision statements: register some DLL, install [Chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org/), and install a Chocolatey package.

Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "regsvr32 foo/Foo.dll"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "choco install foo -y"
```

Output:

```
PS> vagrant provision
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline PowerShell script
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline PowerShell script
==> default: Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\Windows\Temp\WinRM_Elevated_Shell.log: The
==> default: process cannot access the file 'C:\Windows\Temp\WinRM_Elevated_Shell.log' becau
==> default: se it is being used by another process.
==> default: At C:\tmp\vagrant-elevated-shell.ps1:19 char:6
==> default: +   del <<<<  $out_file
==> default:     + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Windows\Temp\WinRM_Elevated_Shel
==> default:    l.log:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
==> default:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell
==> default:    .Commands.RemoveItemCommand
The following WinRM command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -OutputFormat Text -file c:\tmp\vagrant-shell.ps1

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\Windows\Temp\WinRM_Elevated_Shell.log: The
process cannot access the file 'C:\Windows\Temp\WinRM_Elevated_Shell.log' becau
se it is being used by another process.
At C:\tmp\vagrant-elevated-shell.ps1:19 char:6
+   del <<<<  $out_file
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Windows\Temp\WinRM_Elevated_Shel
   l.log:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell
   .Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

I need to confirm the behavior of the heredoc version:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SCRIPT
  regsvr32 foo/Foo.dll
  iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
  choco install foo -y
SCRIPT
```

And reducing the script to any 2 commands, even just `echo`s:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo %COMPUTERNAME%"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo %COMPUTERNAME%"
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `-Force` to the `del $out_file` statement in the [`vagrant-elevated-shell.ps1`](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/plugins/communicators/winrm/scripts/elevated_shell.ps1.erb) script?

Comment: I have not mucked with Vagrant's files... I'm assuming that's in `C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant` somewhere? And I wasn't sure this was a bug yet, hence the SO question and not a GitHub issue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [#3816](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3816) is the answer. It worked for me. Adding `privileged: false` to the end of the `provision` call, should do it.

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))", privileged: false
```